# My if statement don't work in my application

Tags: android

In my sample code , I have problem. I want check all of if-statements but it just run the last If-statements(it just run the first and the last if).and finally I want to show the a1-a10. but it doesn't work.

here: I compare my Question id (qid) with the first question in my unit.and check the item that user select.then I show the question and I add my question id(qid).

```
    if (qid == unitid) {
        if (rda.isChecked()) {
            a1 = rda.getText().toString();
        }
        if (rdb.isChecked()) {
            a1 = rdb.getText().toString();
        }
        if (rdc.isChecked()) {
            a1 = rdc.getText().toString();
        }
        if (rdd.isChecked()) {
            a1 = rdd.getText().toString();
        }
    }
    currentQ = quesList.get(qid);

    setQuestionView();
```

qid++;

then: I do this process again for the next question.

```
if (qid < unitid + 10) {
{


grp.clearCheck();
currentQ = quesList.get(qid);
setQuestionView();

if (qid == unitid + 1) {
    qid++;
    if (rda.isChecked()) {
        a2 = rda.getText().toString();
    }
    if (rdb.isChecked()) {
        a2 = rdb.getText().toString();
    }
    if (rdc.isChecked()) {
        a2 = rdc.getText().toString();
    }
    if (rdd.isChecked()) {
        a2 = rdd.getText().toString();
    }
}


currentQ = quesList.get(qid);
setQuestionView();
if (qid == unitid + 2) {
    qid++;
    if (rda.isChecked()) {
        a3 = rda.getText().toString();
    }
    if (rdb.isChecked()) {
        a3 = rdb.getText().toString();
    }
    if (rdc.isChecked()) {
        a3 = rdc.getText().toString();
    }
    if (rdd.isChecked()) {
        a3 = rdd.getText().toString();
    }
}


currentQ = quesList.get(qid);
setQuestionView();
if (qid == unitid + 3) {
    if (rda.isChecked()) {
        a4 = rda.getText().toString();
    }
    if (rdb.isChecked()) {
        a4 = rdb.getText().toString();
    }
    if (rdc.isChecked()) {
        a4 = rdc.getText().toString();
    }
    if (rdd.isChecked()) {
        a4 = rdd.getText().toString();
    }
}


currentQ = quesList.get(qid);
setQuestionView();
if (qid == unitid + 4) {
    if (rda.isChecked()) {
        a5 = rda.getText().toString();
    }
    if (rdb.isChecked()) {
        a5 = rdb.getText().toString();
    }
    if (rdc.isChecked()) {
        a5 = rdc.getText().toString();
    }
    if (rdd.isChecked()) {
        a5 = rdd.getText().toString();
    }
}


currentQ = quesList.get(qid);
setQuestionView();
if (qid == unitid + 5) {
    if (rda.isChecked()) {
        a6 = rda.getText().toString();
    }
    if (rdb.isChecked()) {
        a6 = rdb.getText().toString();
    }
    if (rdc.isChecked()) {
        a6 = rdc.getText().toString();
    }
    if (rdd.isChecked()) {
        a6 = rdd.getText().toString();
    }
}


currentQ = quesList.get(qid);
setQuestionView();
if (qid == unitid + 6) {
    if (rda.isChecked()) {
        a7 = rda.getText().toString();
    }
    if (rdb.isChecked()) {
        a7 = rdb.getText().toString();
    }
    if (rdc.isChecked()) {
        a7 = rdc.getText().toString();
    }
    if (rdd.isChecked()) {
        a7 = rdd.getText().toString();
    }
}


currentQ = quesList.get(qid);
setQuestionView();
if (qid == unitid + 7) {
    if (rda.isChecked()) {
        a8 = rda.getText().toString();
    }
    if (rdb.isChecked()) {
        a8 = rdb.getText().toString();
    }
    if (rdc.isChecked()) {
        a8 = rdc.getText().toString();
    }
    if (rdd.isChecked()) {
        a8 = rdd.getText().toString();
    }
}


currentQ = quesList.get(qid);
setQuestionView();
if (qid == unitid + 8) {
    if (rda.isChecked()) {
        a9 = rda.getText().toString();
    }
    if (rdb.isChecked()) {
        a9 = rdb.getText().toString();
    }
    if (rdc.isChecked()) {
        a9 = rdc.getText().toString();
    }
    if (rdd.isChecked()) {
        a9 = rdd.getText().toString();
    }
}


currentQ = quesList.get(qid);
setQuestionView();
if (qid == unitid + 9) {
    if (rda.isChecked()) {
        a10 = rda.getText().toString();
    }
    if (rdb.isChecked()) {
        a10 = rdb.getText().toString();
    }
    if (rdc.isChecked()) {
        a10 = rdc.getText().toString();
    }
    if (rdd.isChecked()) {
        a10 = rdd.getText().toString();
    }
}
```

but It just show the first and the last if. It doesn't run the other if-statement.

Comment: yes , they are string.

Comment: Instead of writing this many lines of code just write a loop for that.

Comment: can you suggest any sample to learn loop?@ali786

Comment: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_loop_control.htm

Answer (score 0):

if it is String, you should compare like this:

```
if(qid.eqlualsIgnoreCase(unitId)){
//code
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As you are saying that it is String then your logic is incorrect qid should be an integer type.

```
if (qid < unitid + 10) {
 for(int i=0; i<10; i++)
 grp.clearCheck();
 currentQ = quesList.get(qid);
 setQuestionView();

 if (qid == unitid + ++i) //if qid is 1 or if qid initialized to 0 put i instead of ++i  
 {
    qid++;
    if (rda.isChecked()) {
        a[i] = rda.getText().toString();
    }
    if (rdb.isChecked()) {
        a[i] = rdb.getText().toString();
    }
    if (rdc.isChecked()) {
        a[i] = rdc.getText().toString();
    }
    if (rdd.isChecked()) {
        a[i] = rdd.getText().toString();
    }
}
currentQ = quesList.get(qid);

setQuestionView();
```

This just an example you may do but you need to create array and have to modify many other things. And what you are using in your if should be an integer type.

Comment: qid are integer but my a1-a10 are string . they don't have any relation together. cause I don't even compare them. my main problem is that it doesn't enter in if all.

Comment: It is zero. qid = my question id, unitid = the id of question that start the first of each unit

Comment: can u tell me how I use and identify a[i]?

Comment: just write another loop for identifying a[i], a[] will be a string array.

Comment: I can't identify the string array. I' m just new with java & programming.